# Move a view from one view to another

Tags: android, imageview

I have to move from x to y point. There are 10 views horizontal.I want to move a imageView to move from x view to the y view.

```
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, viewTwo.getX()-viewOne.getX(),0 , viewTwo.getY()-viewOne.getY());
    animation.setRepeatMode(0);
    animation.setDuration(3000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    viewOne.startAnimation(animation);
```

but viewTwo.getX() and viewOne.getX() returns 0.0.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to look up `measure()` method to get X position value !
Like, measure the view until Y position, the view-width on the left of Y position would be the result what you wanted.